# qplot and anti-aliasing in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 library and am working with the qplot command
I know I can save my output as an anti-aliased image file by using the following command after my qplot

```
ggsave(file="filename.png")
```

But how about my LCD display? is there any way to see a plot on the monitor as anti-aliased grpah?

Comment: I think that is between you and your window manager.

Comment: Is there a way to tell R to anti-alias my plot windows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Windows, there is no built-in anti-aliasing. I don't know whether it is planned for future releases or not. You can get a Cairo-based graphics device from either the `cairoDevice` or `Cairo` packages; however, you will need to install `GTK+` first:

Download and install `Gtk+ 2.12.9 Runtime Environment Revision 2` from http://gladewin32.sourceforge.net/

Another option would be to use Java-based graphics through `JGR` (`http://jgr.markushelbig.org/`). Also a `Qt`-based device is under development, I think.

Comment: I installed Cairo without having to install GTK+, on Windows 7 with R 3.1.1 64-bit. Antialising is nice.

Answer (score 17):

As others have mentioned, R's built-in Windows graphics device does not do anti-aliasing. But nowadays it's easy to install the Cairo graphics device which does.

At the R console:

```
install.packages('Cairo',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
```

To test:

```
plot(rnorm(1000)) # non-antialiased (on Windows)
library('Cairo')
CairoWin()
plot(rnorm(1000)) # antialiased!
```

[More](http://www.rforge.net/Cairo/files/)

Answer (score 5):

If you have Cairo installed (see the other answers), to save it as an anti-aliased PNG, just change your code to:

`ggsave(file="filename.png", type="cairo-png")`

as specified [here](https://gist.github.com/dsparks/3777731).

But for what purpose do you want to "see a plot on the monitor as anti-aliased graph" or "anti-alias my plot windows"? If you mean like in the Plots window (tab) in RStudio, I am not sure that can be done, it serves basically just as a preview. I suggest you save the graph to a file and then use this file to display it or for any other purpose.

Comment: I would recommend use `type = "cairo"` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I just checked. I was wrong in my earlier comment. From `help(x11)` where a lot of detail is available -- the new Cairo-based devices do have anti-aliasing available:

> x11                 package:grDevices 
>   R Documentation
>
> X Window System Graphics
>
> Description:
>
> ```
>  ‘X11’ starts a graphics device driver for the X Window System
>  (version 11).  This can only be done on machines/accounts that
>  have access to an X server.
>
>  ‘x11’ is recognized as a synonym for ‘X11’.
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>  X11(display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg, canvas,
>      fonts, xpos, ypos, title, type, antialias)
>
>  X11.options(..., reset = FALSE)
> ```
>
> Arguments:
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>  fonts: X11 font description strings into which weight, slant and
>       size will be substituted.  There are two, the first for fonts
>       1 to 4 and the second for font 5, the symbol font.  See
>       section ‘Fonts’.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>  antialias: for cairo types, the typeof anti-aliasing (if any) to be
>       used.  One of ‘c("default", "none", "gray", "subpixel")’.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Details:
>
> ```
>  The defaults for all of the arguments of ‘X11’ are set by
>  ‘X11.options’: the ‘Arguments’ section gives the ‘factory-fresh’
>  defaults.
>
>  The initial size and position are only hints, and may not be acted
>  on by the window manager.  Also, some systems (especially laptops)
>  are set up to appear to have a screen of a different size to the
>  physical screen.
>
>  Option ‘type’ selects between two separate devices: R can be built
>  with support for neither, ‘type = "Xlib"’ or both.  Where both are
>  available, types ‘"cairo"’ and ‘"nbcairo"’ offer
>
>     * antialiasing of text and lines.
>
>     * translucent colours.
>
>     * scalable text, including to sizes like 4.5 pt.
>
>     * full support for UTF-8, so on systems with suitable fonts you
>       can plot in many languages on a single figure (and this will
>       work even in non-UTF-8 locales).  The output should be
>       locale-independent.
>
>  ‘type = "nbcairo"’ is the same device as ‘type="cairo"’ without
>  buffering: which is faster will depend on the X11 connection.
>  Both will be slower than ‘type = "Xlib"’, especially on a slow X11
>  connection as all the rendering is done on the machine running R
>  rather than in the X server.
>
>  All devices which use an X11 server (including the ‘type = "Xlib"’
>  versions of bitmap devices such as ‘png’) share internal
>  structures, which means that they must use the same ‘display’ and
>  visual.  If you want to change display, first close all such
>  devices.
> ```
>
> [...and more...]

Comment: Alright, now here is my question: I get an error when I type  X11(type="cairo") I get "Error in X11(type = "cairo") : unused argument(s) (type = "cairo")" I have cairo loaded but do not know how I can change my X11. I am using R 2.9.2 on a Win XP. Do I need to trash my whole system and get a Mac to get anti-aliasing on my display?

Comment: I was sort-of worried about that part. I know Cairo came from Gnome / Gtk and is right at home on Linux, but I thought this was cross-platform.  What do you get when you call `capabilities()` in your R session on XP? I have a 'cairo' TRUE there right at the end.

Comment: I get FALSE, but thanks anyways, very interesting journey. I will try it on an Ubuntu later. Thanks again for looking into it.

Comment: My pleasure. Cairo is a good thing with anti-aliasing, alpha-blending and all that -- but it also has a cost of slower rendering.

Comment: Ahh, and I see that Felix had the goods. So on Windows you need one of the Cairo packages which require you to get Gtk+ for the underlying technologies. Makes sense.