# Getting anti-aliased plots with R on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, graphics, plot, x11

I upgraded my system and reinstalled R, and now my standard X-11 plots are not anti-aliased -- they look jagged and the font looks bad.

I seem to recall a problem like this in the past but don't remember what I did about it.

Some other info:

- `qplot` also comes out non-anti-aliased
- plotting to a `png` device produces non-anti-aliased output as well
- plotting to a `pdf` device, however, produces nice looking anti-aliased output

Another thing: I've been running this version of R/Ubuntu for a while now, a couple months or so.  I don't know if this plotting problem started immediately with the new R install, or if I did something after that to break it.  I don't remember noticing the lack anti-aliasing before, but I may not have been paying attention or doing a lot of plotting.

Anyone know what the fix is?  Currently I am running R 3.2.1, compiled from the source, with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

A few more things.  Following [the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898101/qplot-and-anti-aliasing-in-r) I tried installing Cairo, but it failed.  Also, I've been able to get non-anti-aliased plots in R/linux without installing Cairo in the past, and I'd rather not install extra things if not necessary.

Here are my `X11.options()`:

```
$display
[1] ""

$width
[1] NA

$height
[1] NA

$pointsize
[1] 12

$bg
[1] "transparent"

$canvas
[1] "white"

$gamma
[1] 1

$colortype
[1] "true"

$maxcubesize
[1] 256

$fonts
[1] "-adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
[2] "-adobe-symbol-medium-r-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$family
[1] "sans"

$xpos
[1] NA

$ypos
[1] NA

$title
[1] ""

$type
[1] "Xlib"

$antialias
[1] "default"
```

Comment: I have this problem too. I know that a solution exists, because when I install the "rmarkdown" library, and use `render` to process my knitr file, then it produces pretty plots with anti-aliased lines *and* fonts. However, I'm still trying to figure out what sort of magic it uses to accomplish this. By the way, I'm just working on the fonts - I can get anti-aliased lines with e.g. `ggsave(file="filename.png",type="cairo-png")`...

Answer (score 2):

I'm running R 3.4.0 and I get anti-aliased lines, "points", and plot axes by default for `X11()` and `png()` devices.

However, there are certain "Microsoft fonts" packages which needs to be installed on my system in order to get anti-aliased text. I can't speak for Ubuntu, but on Arch Linux the package names were "ttf-ms-fonts" and "fontconfig-ttf-ms-fonts", both in AUR. A good Google search should turn up similar packages for your own system.

Here is are some plots produced by the `png()` device with and without "ttf-ms-fonts" installed.

- Without "ttf-ms-fonts":

[image: brownian-motion-no-msfonts]

- With "ttf-ms-fonts":

[image: brownian-motion-with-msfonts]

I hope it is possible to see that the lines and circles in both plots are anti-aliased, but only the second plot has anti-aliased text.

Here is the code I used to produce the above plots:

```
set.seed(1);
brownian=cumsum(runif(1e3,min=-1));
png("brownian-no-msfonts.png",height=400);
par(cex=1.3);
plot(brownian,ylim=c(-10,15),
    ylab="Position",xlab="Time",main="Brownian Motion");
lines(brownian+7);
dev.off()
```

I've confirmed that I need both "ttf-ms-fonts" and "fontconfig-ttf-ms-fonts" (the latter I think configures certain fonts to be used by default) in order to get the anti-aliased text in R, although only the first package is needed to e.g. get anti-aliased text in Firefox.

However, I've been playing with the "knitr" package and I noticed that if I compile my documents using "render" from the "rmarkdown" package, then it can produce anti-aliased plots with or without the "ttf-ms-fonts" package installed. I haven't figured out how it does this. I know that it runs Pandoc which produces HTML with embedded fonts, but I'm not sure if the "rmarkdown" package itself includes fonts, or if it just has a better idea of where to find good ones on my system.

I feel superficial for spending time on this, but whatever.